# ELK and mysql gepoint

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I need to create a kibana dashboard with a coordinate map.
I import data from a mysql database with latitude and longitute.
But I can't create a field type "geo_point", and after a long search I come to ask you for help.

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution :
In logstash I specify output elasticsearch "document_type" and without it, it works

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your mappings before hand as elasticsearch will no longer automatically pick up geo points. this reference link has a mapping in it. your index must be empty before you upload a mapping

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html

Comment: I use a template to define a geo_point type field, but now another problem has happened I have this error when running logstash `elasticsearch - Could not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>"196366", :_index=>"index", :_type=>"reporting", :routing=>nil}, #<LogStash::Event:0xa9f0db3>], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"index", "_type"=>"reporting", "_id"=>"196366", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"mapper [location] of different type, current_type [geo_point], merged_type [ObjectMapper]"}}}}`

Comment: This is a type conflict between geo_point and objectmapper (no idea what the object mapper is though) basically ES is expecting a different type of object to your input, use the get mapping endpoint and post it here

Comment: I have only that on my mapping
 `{
    "index_trecobat": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "location": {
                    "type": "geo_point"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`

Comment: cool that's good. so your index is set up correctly but the data you're sending to it is in the wrong format or appears incorrect to elastic at least. Ensure that your data looks as the examples on the link above and you should be good

Comment: cool, if you post an example of the location data you're attempting to input, might be able to help further